# Change the baseUrl for a Website project in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express, visual-studio-2013

I have a website project and it was all working fine until I updated my OS to Win8.1 this morning. This also included VS2013 which I used earlier as well but on Win 7. I had to configure the IIS Express to use proper authentication settings and allow parts of config file. That out the way, I fired up a website project and it had lost its baseUrl property ie. everything crashed. We have to use baseUrl as we use it in production sites like www.xyz.com/myApps/Calculator & www.xyz.com/myApps/RaiseABug etc.

Since, the project does not run in VS2013 at all... I did a bit of research and found this :

> http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793989

and

> http://forums.asp.net/t/1978467.aspx?Can+t+change+URL+for+ASP+NET+website

but none of them really answer the question. And the workaround in my first link doesn't work. The option to set the baseUrl is greyed out and changing it in the solution file doesn't get affected.

So, may I take this opportunity to ask you.. HOW DO I CHANGE THE BASE-URL and GET IT TO WORK WITH IIS-EXPRESS

This [image](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_cb5Mk8MlpxekNsdjlDb2xrd2s/edit?pli=1) shows what I get when I try to edit the url from the VS2013 front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the remote Web server for a Web site project

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the Web site project
   for which you want to specify a Web server, and then click Property
   Pages.
2. In the Property Pages dialog box, click the Start Options tab.
3. **Under Server, click Use custom server.**
4. In the Base URL box, type the URL that Visual Studio should start
   when it runs the current project.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178108(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178108%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If that option is unavailable, check [this article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793989)

- Make sure you have most recent release of VS.NET 2013
- Modify *.sln file (as described in the above link) and add required url and set UseIISExpress to false

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I get is something like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_cb5Mk8MlpxekNsdjlDb2xrd2s/edit?pli=1 ..... Don't have the option to change the path whatsoever.

Comment: I have tried editing the *.sln file but it doesn't affect at all, which is weird. Let me see if updating VS works.

Comment: The workaround did not work either. Anyway, I can finally convince my manager to upgrade all the websites to webapps.. I am sure if someone follows the steps you mentioned, their problem is more likely to be solved.